# Is $[\bar{\mathbb Q}:\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R]=2$?

Tags: field-theory

> Is $[\bar{\mathbb Q}:\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R]=2$ ?

I think it is true that $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb C=\bar{\mathbb Q}$, because I've heard that the closure of the reals is $\mathbb C$. And $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$, so using this fact, we have $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R$, intersection of $2$ fields, again a field.

but does the index necessarily have to be an integer as in the group theory ?

Comment: Complex conjugation generates a subgroup of order two in $Gal(\bar{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$. The claim follows from this.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Gal-notation is new to me

Comment: It stands for the Galois group. So if $L$ is an extension field of $K$, then $Gal(L/K)$ is the group of automorphisms of $L$ that fix all the elements of the subfield. Sorry about not ascertaining that you knew about the concepts. I expect that you will encounter those soon. Enjoy! They are fun.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Thanks a lot, although your solution sounded a bit more concrete, the others should suffice for this problem.

Comment: Sure. The others have given fine solutions! My suggestion is not very helpful unless you have seen those bits of Galois theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition the index is the *dimension* of $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ as a vector space over $\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap \mathbb R$, so it is always an integer (if finite).

If we let $F=\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap \mathbb R$, it is not difficult to prove that every element of $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ can be written $a+bi$ with $a,b\in F$, so the dimension (and therefore the index) is indeed 2.

Comment: it is always an integer, or infinite.

Comment: @JHance: Edited.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Let $n=a+bi$ be a root of some $P\in\mathbb Q[X]$ s.t. $n$ is algebraic. Then $a$ and $b$ are necessarily algebraic, since $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ is a field and therefore closed under conjugation, hence $\displaystyle u=\frac{n+\bar n}{2}, v=\frac{n-\bar n}{2i}$ are algebraic ?

Comment: @OBDA: Yes. ${}{}$

Comment: @OBDA - An algebraic field is not necessarily closed under conjugation. Consider $$\mathbb Q\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\cdot\sqrt[3]2\right)\neq\mathbb Q\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\sqrt[3]2\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

The real algebraic numbers form a field, yes. More generally, the intersection of two subfields of a field is again a field.

A number is algebraic if and only if its real and imaginary part are algebraic. 
Thus one can write every algebraic number $a$ as $r_1 + i r_2$ with $r_1,r_2$ real algebraic numbers.

The degree is thus $2$ as you suspect.

The degree of the field extension is the dimension of the large field as a vector space over the smaller. It is thus a positive integer or an infinite cardinal, like the index of a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $[\overline{\mathbb Q}:\overline{\mathbb Q}\cap \mathbb R]=2$, since you attain the former from the latter by adjoining $i$.

The index is always either a positive integer or infinite, since it represents the cardinality of a basis of a vector space.

Comment: yes but, how did you conclude  $[\bar{\mathbb Q}:\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R]=[\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb C:\bar{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R]\overset?=[\mathbb C:\mathbb R]$